# Broken symbolic link while creating link from source directory

Tags: command-line, 18.04, symbolic-link

I created a symbolic link for a file named `zotero.desktop` to be placed in the directory `~/.local/share/applications`, as below:

`<At source file's directory>$ ln -s zotero.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`

the symbolic link got created, but was broken and did not work. Also, tried double-clicking on the file Ubuntu Desktop, but had the alert of "Boken link".

Then tried the below command, and it worked:

`<At ~/.local/share/applications/>$ ln -s <source-dir>/zotero.desktop .`

Is there any explanation for this?

Answer (score 2):

The command `ln -s zotero.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/` creates the softlink `~/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop` which points to itself, `~/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop`:

```
$ ls -l ~/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 14 May 29 11:33 /home/terdon/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop -> zotero.desktop
```

This is because the format of the `ln` command is:

```
ln source target
```

Since you gave the source as a file name, without a path, that is taken to be a file name in the target directory. I don't know where your target is, but assuming it is in the directory you ran the `ln` command from, you want to run this:

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/zotero.desktop
ln -s "$PWD/zotero.desktop" ~/.local/share/applications/
```

In general, you need to remember that softlinks are relative. So for example, I can do this:

```
$ tree
.
├── file
└── foo

1 directory, 1 file
$ ln -s ../file foo/
terdon@tpad foo $ tree
.
├── file
└── foo
    └── file -> ../file
```

When I ran `ln -s ../file foo`, that means "create a symlink in the directory foo which points to ../file". But the `../file` will be with respect to the symlink. So it will point to a file called `file` *above* the directory `foo`.

The simplest way to always get it right is to move into the target directory first and then run the `ln` command there, so that you get the relative path right.